# FormClosing and Unhandled Exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am inheriting my class from a form that has a handler for FormClosing (it's overridable so I can override it and do MsgBox("Ha") there before calling the base method). In my Shared Sub New() I have:

```
' Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event.
AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf Application_ThreadException

' Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. 
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf CurrentDomain_UnhandledException

'For Console applications you should use the System.AppDomain.UnhandledException event
AddHandler Thread.GetDomain().UnhandledException, AddressOf CurrentDomain_UnhandledException
```

If I throw an exception in my form outside of a try/catch I am noticing two different behaviors:

1. If I am using the VS debugger I get an unhandled exception and it seems that my unhandled exception handler is called. The formClosing event handler does not seem to be called.
2. If I am NOT using the VS debugger then the FormClosing Handler is being
   called but the Unhandled Exception handler isn't called.

I am stomped why the Unhandled Exception handlers are not being called in #2. Ideally I would like (in both cases) to have the Unhandled Exception to be called and then the FormClosing event handler to be called. What am I missing?

(SOME SAMPLE CODE) -- THIS demonstrates how different exceptions are thrown if you run using debugger in VS (just pressing F5) or when you run without a debugger (just pressing CTRL-F5). This doesn't reproduce the problem perfectly but maybe my problem has to do with the ThreadException being handled differently by the base class.

Form1 (Set as Startup in your project).

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form2

    Shared Sub New()
        ' Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event. 
        AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf Application_ThreadException

        ' Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event.  
        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf CurrentDomain_UnhandledException

    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        MsgBox("UnhandledException caught")
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub Application_ThreadException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
        MsgBox("ThreadException caught")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Login()
        Throw New Exception("Ha!")

        MyBase.Login()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Form2_FormClosing(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs)
        MsgBox("Form1Closing")

        MyBase.Form2_FormClosing(sender, e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form2:

```
Public Class Form2

  Protected Overridable Sub Form2_FormClosing(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        MsgBox("Form2Closing")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        Login()
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Login()
        MsgBox("Form2 LoggingIn")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Any particular reason for having a Shared constructor in your form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I catch an exception in a GUI thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770700/how-do-i-catch-an-exception-in-a-gui-thread)

Comment: Shared constructor ensures I call the unhandled exception handler only 1 time

Comment: @Hans but the point is that the ThreadException is not raised when I am running without a debugger. I would have expected it to be raised.

Comment: Well, that's the *exact* opposite of what should happen.  Post code so we can all try this for ourselves.  I'm definitely interested at what it looks like, this has been banged billions of times.

Comment: This works as it should when I try this code.  Getting "ThreadException caught" without the debugger.

Comment: Did you try Initiating the Form2_FormClosing() within the  UnhandledException() ?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for not using comment section, perhaps it should be there instead (not enough rep). Just thought I'd throw my 2c research in:

- Using VS2010 SP1.
- Created WinApp project with default settings.
- Ported the above code, adding "Inherits Form" statement to Form2 class definition.
- With debugger - getting "UnhandledException caught" message and then debugger breaks at Throw New Exception("Ha!") line, continuing throws me in an infinite loop (getting "UnhandledException caught" message again etc.).
- Without debugger - getting "UnhandledException caught", and execution continues after that, when closing the form, getting "Form1Closing" and "Form2Closing".

Everything seems to be working as expected.